# Bot on Pi crashes after using any Async api calls a second time

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, raspbian, discord, discord.net

I put my Discord bot on a Rasberry Pi but now I'm having an issue with it. When I try to use a command, it works the first time. But using it a second time, instead of working it just says "A MessageReceived handler is blocking the gateway task.". Shortly afterwards it then says

> System.Exception: Server missed last heartbeat
>         at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in :0
>         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0003e] in :0
>         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in :0
>         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in :0
>         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in :0
>         at Discord.ConnectionManager+<>c__DisplayClass28_0+<b__0>d.MoveNext () [0x0014b] in :0

and disconnects, trying to reconnect some but erroring everytime. I'm not using the command interface, but I am using async/await. It works on my normal computer perfectly fine, only breaks on my Pi.

```
using Discord;
using Discord.WebSocket;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GlurrrBotDiscord
{
    public class Program
    {
        DiscordSocketClient client;

        static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        public async Task MainAsync()
        {
            client = new DiscordSocketClient();

            try
            {
                using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("botcode.txt"))
                {
                    string code = sr.ReadLine();
                    await client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, code);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Code not found");
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }

            await client.StartAsync();
            await client.SetGameAsync("praise");

            client.MessageReceived += handleMessage;

            await Task.Delay(-1);
        }

        private async Task handleMessage(SocketMessage msg)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(msg.Author + " : " + msg.Content);

            if(msg.Content.Contains("/leave"))
            {
                var embed = new EmbedBuilder() {
                    Title = msg.Author + " has left",
                    Description = msg.Author + " has left the Discord and would like everyone to know they did. They are very triggered.",
                    Color = Color.DarkRed,
                };

                await msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, embed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Complete code is at https://github.com/Silthreent/Glurrr-Discord-Bot

Comment: Post the relevant code **here**.  [mcve]

Comment: Well it's any time it uses two Async calls.

```if(msg.Content.Contains("/leave"))  
            {  
                var embed = new EmbedBuilder() {  
                    Title = msg.Author + " has left",  
                    Description = msg.Author + " has left the Discord and would like everyone to know they did. They are very triggered.",
                    Color = Color.DarkRed,
                };

                await msg.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, embed);  
            }```

Is probably the easiest place to show.
~~new to stack comments; looks like garbage~~

Comment: You do not put code in comments, you need to edit your question and put the Minimal Complete Verifiable example there. Please read the link MickyD sent you before you update your question, the code you posted in the comment is not acceptable for a example.

Comment: Alright, I updated the main post, sorry for the trouble.

Comment: As opposed to editing your answer into your question, you should post it as an answer instead and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by switching to DiscordSharpPlus rather than using DiscordNet, still don't actually know what the problem was.

Answer (score 0):

The `Server missed last heartbeat at` is a consequence of `A MessageReceived handler is blocking the gateway task` which means that one of the commands you are running uses the gateway, and keeps it occupied long enough to let the connection timeout (~30 seconds).

To fix this you will have to implement [a command handler](https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/guides/commands.html) which is part of the basic bot implementation. This will allow you to run commands async, preventing the thread blocking. You can also take a look at the [bot sample](https://github.com/Aux/Discord.Net-Example) to see said implementation in action

Comment: No matter how long I wait, it will still break on the second command. I tried using a different bot I have that uses command handler, and it actually breaks even harder. It breaks after the very first command, fulfilling that command and then giving the MessageRecieved handler issue without need of a second command.

Comment: @silthreent and u are user that the handler has its mode set to async. And the function was decorated with the async mode attribute?

Comment: Setting runmode to async doesn't give me the MessageRecieved handler message, however no message beyond the first is ever posted.

Comment: @Silthreent also make sure you have your loglevel set to LogLevel = LogSeverity.Verbose. Or take a look at my [answer over here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45736380/2030635) to get some logging in your application